# cget not found after pip installation

Tags: ubuntu, curl, pip

I install `cget` on my Ubutun 18.04 machine following [this guide](http://cget.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/intro.html#installing-cget) with:

```
pip install cget
```

The terminal shows:

```
Collecting cget
Collecting six>=1.10 (from cget)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting subprocess32 (from cget)
Collecting click==6.6 (from cget)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1c/7c/10b4132dd952b6a04e37626258825b8aa8c1eb99545f2eb26a77c21efb55/click-6.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: six, subprocess32, click, cget
Successfully installed cget-0.1.6 click-6.6 six-1.11.0 subprocess32-3.5.2
```

Afterwards, I run:

```
cget install curl
```

It complains:

```
Command 'cget' not found, did you mean:

  command 'mget' from snap mget (0.1.2)
  command 'cset' from deb cpuset
  command 'cgpt' from deb cgpt
  command 'cfget' from deb cfget
  command 'wget' from deb wget
  command 'kget' from deb kget
  command 'pget' from deb pbuilder-scripts
  command 'dget' from deb devscripts
  command 'cgget' from deb cgroup-tools
  command 'cgset' from deb cgroup-tools
  command 'bget' from deb ax25-tools
  command 'cjet' from deb printer-driver-cjet

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.
```

What exactly happened?  I am at a loss here.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List the installed files with

```
pip show --files cget
```

Find out in what directory `pip` installed script `cget` and add it to your `$PATH`.

Comment: Thanks!  Got the rest of it done with method 2 here: https://hackprogramming.com/2-ways-to-permanently-set-path-variable-in-ubuntu/